# Access console logs in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I'm just getting to grips with NativeScript, and while I like what I'm seeing so far, I can't work out how to look at the console output when I'm running (e.g.):

```
tns run ios --emulator
```

That command immediately exists to the prompt, so it's not outputting console logs in the terminal window. I can see some references online to AppBuilder, a paid-for Telerik tool. Is that the only way to see console logs while debugging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try 
`tns device log`

and `tns device log -h` for help.

Comment: tns device log shows running amount of useless data. Unable to view console log.

Answer (score 1):

The nativescript cli has a [`tns debug`](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/wiki/Debug-command-specification) command which you can use after you `run`.